# Unsafe in the anchor tag link which was buit dynamically in njavascript

Tags: angularjs, anchor, unsafe

Am facing the unsafe issue with the dynamic anchor tag build on the javascript Below is my anchor tag build in javascript .

```
 var linkCellTemplate = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">' +
           '  <a  class="text-blue-color text-underline" ng-href="javascript:viewCPClaim(\'{{row.entity.TagNumber}}\');">{{row.entity.TagNumber}}</a>' +
           '</div>';
```

Below is the compile provider that i used but it didnt have any effect. Am still getting the unsafe and it inhibits the javascript post and redirection.

```
  angular.module("app").config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(unsafe:javascript‌​)/);}]);app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|chrome-extension):/);}]);
```

Any help is highly appreciated on this.